# Invoice pdf in php with wkhtmltopdf snappy Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Hi every body i have to make an invoice pdf in my LARAVEL project.

I succeeed to generate a pdf with this code :

```
  $path_name_file = '../ArchivePdf/'. $name_file . '.pdf';

        if ($document->type->type == 'A'){
            $pdf = SnappyPdf::loadView('ribbon.report.pdf-achat', ['document' =>$document])
            ->save($path_name_file);


        }else{
            $pdf = SnappyPdf::loadView('ribbon.report.pdf-new', ['document' =>$document])->save($path_name_file);

        }
```

My problem is in the blade view (HTML template) that i want to put an header and a footer and a main table with items

I want that the footer will be on all pages

How can i do that?

Thanks

That is my actual html view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PDF Devis</title>

    {{--<link href="{{ asset("/css/style_pdf.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--}}
    <style>
        .header-1{
            border-top-left-radius: 7px;
            border-top-right-radius: 7px;
            /*left: 5%;*/
            width: 100%;
            border-style: solid;
            font-size: 13px;
            border-width: 2px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.22);
            text-align: center;


        }

        .line{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .line tr{
            padding: 0;
        }
        .td-20{
            width:20%
        }
        .td-30{
            width:30%
        }
        .td-70{
            width: 70%;
        }
        .td-40{
            width: 40%;
        }
        .td-50{
            width: 50%;
        }
        .img img{
            width:100%; height:auto;
        }
        .name-soc{
            font-size: 25px;
            color: orangered;
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: arial;
            font-style: bold;
        }
        .space{
          padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .title{
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 50px;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.89);
            font-size: 25px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .items{

        }
        .more_line{
            height: 17px;
        }
        /*.items-table{*/
            /*page-break-after: always;*/
            /*page-break-inside: avoid;*/
        /*}*/
        thead { display: table-header-group }
        tfoot { display: table-row-group }
        .items-row { page-break-inside: avoid }
        table { border-collapse: separate }
        .note-table{
            text-align: right;
            width: 100%;
        }




    </style>
</header>
<body>

<table class="line">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" class="td-30">
            <div class="img"> <img src="{{ public_path('/ribbon/pdf/fre.jpg') }}" alt="logo"/></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-30">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-40">
            <div class="name-soc">
                דקופלוס פרקט בע״מ
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-30">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-40">
            <div class="name-soc">

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-20">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-20">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-20">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-20">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="line">
    <tr class="entete">
        <td class="logo">

        </td>
        <td class="donnee_soc">
            <div dir="rtl">{{trans('dcp_pdf.num_doc')}} : {{ $document->code }} </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-50">
            <div>
                <table class="header-1" dir="rtl">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">{{trans('dcp_pdf.coord_cust')}}</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.name')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['name'] }} {{ $document['customer']['surname'] }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.adress')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['adress']['street'] }} {{ $document->adress->city->cityT[0]->texte  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.telephone')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['phone'] }} / {{ $document['customer']['phone2']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.mail')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['email']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-50">
            <div>
                <table class="header-1" dir="rtl">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">{{trans('dcp_pdf.coord_fact')}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.name')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['name'] }} {{ $document['customer']['surname'] }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.adress')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['adress']['street'] }} {{ $document->adress->city->cityT[0]->texte  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.telephone')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['phone'] }} / {{ $document['customer']['phone2']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.mail')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['email']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2" class="space">
            <div>
                <table class="header-1" dir="rtl">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">{{trans('dcp_pdf.coord_livraison')}}</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.name')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['name'] }} {{ $document['customer']['surname'] }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.adress')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['adress']['street'] }} {{ $document->adress->city->cityT[0]->texte  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.telephone')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['phone'] }} / {{ $document['customer']['phone2']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="" >
                        <td>
                            <div  style="width: 20%">{{trans('dcp_pdf.mail')}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['customer']['email']  }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2" class="space">
            <div class="title" dir="rtl">
                {{ $document->type->typeT[0]->texte }} - {{ $document->code }}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2" class="space">

            <table class="items header-1 items-table" dir="rtl">
            <thead>
                <tr class="more_line">
                    <th class="Désignation" >{{trans('dcp_pdf.desc_article')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.conditionnement')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.quantity_m2')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.nb_colis')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.pu_ht')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.discount')}}</th>
                    <th class="other">{{trans('dcp_pdf.total_ht')}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

                @foreach($document->items as $item)

                    <tr class="1 items-row">
                        <td class="Designation" dir="rtl"><div dir="rtl">{{  $item->material->textes[0]->texte }}</div></td>
                        <td class="Cdt"></td>
                        <td class="Qtem2">{{  $item->quantity }}</td>
                        <td class="Nb_colis">{{  $item->qte_col }}</td>
                        <td class="PU">{{    number_format($item->price, 2, '.', ',')  }}</td>
                        <td class="Rem">{{    number_format($item->discount, 2, '.', ',')  }} {{  $item->typeRemise->code }}</td>
                        <td class="Total"> {{    number_format($item->price_wo_vat, 2, '.', ',')  }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                @for ($i = $document->items->count(); $i < 20; $i++)

                    <tr class="more_line">
                        <td class="Designation" dir="rtl"><div dir="rtl"></div></td>
                        <td class="Cdt"></td>
                        <td class="Qtem2"></td>
                        <td class="Nb_colis"></td>
                        <td class="PU"></td>
                        <td class="Rem"></td>
                        <td class="Total"></td>
                    </tr>
                @endfor

            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2" >

            <table class="note-table" dir="rtl">

                <tr class="" >

                    <td>
                        <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['note'] }} </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" >
                    <td >
                        <div class="encadre_data">{{ $document['comment'] }} </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-30">
            <div>
                <table class="header-1" dir="rtl">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{trans('dcp_pdf.montant_ht')}}</td>
                        <td>{{    number_format($document->amount_wo_taxe, 2, '.', ',')  }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{trans('dcp_pdf.dont_remise')}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    @if ($document['customer']['code_tva'] === 1)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{trans('dcp_pdf.tva')}} {{    number_format($document->taxe, 2, '.', ',')  }} %</td>
                            <td>{{    number_format($document->amount - $document->amount_wo_taxe, 2, '.', ',')  }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{trans('dcp_pdf.montant_ttc')}}</td>
                        <td>{{    number_format($document->amount, 2, '.', ',')  }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-70">
            <div>
                <table class="header-1" dir="rtl">
                    <tr>
                       <th colspan="4">{{trans('dcp_pdf.reglements')}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <th>{{trans('dcp_pdf.date')}}</th>
                       <th>{{trans('dcp_pdf.description')}}</th>
                       <th>{{trans('dcp_pdf.montant')}}</th>
                       <th>{{trans('dcp_pdf.mode_paiement')}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($document->reglements as $reglement)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $reglement->date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $reglement->description }}</td>
                            <td>{{  number_format($reglement->amount, 2, '.', ',') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $reglement->mode->modePaiementT[0]->texte }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html#Footers%20And%20Headers) about header and footer with `Wkhtmltopdf` support.

**You can try**
*For Header*

```
setOption('header-html', 'Your Header');
```

*For Footer*

```
setOption('footer-html', 'Your Footer');
```

Just make sure that you need to add `<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en-US'>` in the beginning of your header/footer HTML!

Comment: I have to generate it in arabic and english version. And how can i do that i saw this documentation but it is not explicit

Comment: @shmoolki you need to set/change `<html lang='en-US'>` as per your requirement.